No response from github actions when attempting to retrieve vault secrets
When attempting to access Vault secrets from a github action, the "Get Vault Secrets" section returns a 1/error but nothing else (debug is on).
Output:
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Retrieve secret from Vault'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Retrieve secret from Vault
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Loading env
Run hashicorp/vault-action@v3
::group::Get Vault Secrets
Get Vault Secrets
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]Set output errorMessage = 
##[debug]Finishing: Retrieve secret from Vault

My github workflow:
  retrieve-secret-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Retrieve secret from Vault
        uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v3
        with:
          exportToken: true
          method: jwt
          url: https://my-awesome-vault-url
          role: myproject-production
          secrets: |
            secret/data/production testSecret | DEFAULT_TEST_SECRET;  
      - name: Use secret test
        run: |
          TEST_SECRET = "${{ env.DEFAULT_TEST_SECRET }}"

My Vault has the following role myproject-production details:
vault read auth/jwt/role/myproject-production 
{
  "request_id": "0b7ba92b-6994-df82-2c3c-115bace2bca4",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "allowed_redirect_uris": null,
    "bound_audiences": null,
    "bound_claims": {
      "repository": "MyRepo/MyProject"
    },
    "bound_claims_type": "string",
    "bound_subject": "",
    "claim_mappings": null,
    "clock_skew_leeway": 0,
    "expiration_leeway": 0,
    "groups_claim": "",
    "max_age": 0,
    "not_before_leeway": 0,
    "oidc_scopes": null,
    "policies": [
      "myproject-production"
    ],
    "role_type": "jwt",
    "token_bound_cidrs": [],
    "token_explicit_max_ttl": 0,
    "token_max_ttl": 0,
    "token_no_default_policy": false,
    "token_num_uses": 0,
    "token_period": 0,
    "token_policies": [
      "myproject-production"
    ],
    "token_ttl": 600,
    "token_type": "default",
    "ttl": 600,
    "user_claim": "actor",
    "user_claim_json_pointer": false,
    "verbose_oidc_logging": false
  },
  "warnings": null
}


The associated token policy details:
vault policy read myproject-production                    
{
  "policy": "# Read-only permission on 'secret/data/production/*' path\n\npath \"secret/data/production/*\" {\n  capabilities = [ \"read\" ]\n}\n"
}


I'm expecting the secrets to be retrieved but nothing happens and the stage completes with an exit code 1 after ~2min20sec.  No errors or messages.
